# Reading text file and drawing grain structure using value available in file

Tags: python, structure, abaqus

I am working in abaqus to create crystal grains geomtries and assemble by using availble co-ordinates present in text file. I am new to python so please someone help me to read this file and assign values.

You can find the file with this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_hkeWVV98L4MTVCNHMydXlWZ2s.

Here column 8-12 are co-ordinates(x1 & y1, x2 & y2)  and column 13-14 grain or part numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, Code.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the text into multiple text columns
To read any text with the following code and  use it in a list.

```
id1=open('text1.txt','r')
data1=[]
a=id1.readline()
for i in range (100):
    data1.append(float(a))
        a=id1.readline()
id1.close()
```